# pthreads not behaving like expected

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

I currently have the code seen here:

```
<?php

class workerThread extends Thread {
    public function __construct($i) {
        $this->i = $i;
    }

    public function run() {
        echo $this->i . " ";
        sleep(1);
        echo $this->i . " ";
    }
}

for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {
    $workers[$i]= new workerThread($i);
    $workers[$i]->start();
}

?>
```

What I would expect this to do would be to echo `1 2 3 4 5`, wait 1 second, and then echo `1 2 3 4 5`. However, instead it waits for the entire program to finish and then spits out `1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5`. For some reason it is not behaving asynchronously. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Does the same thing using `usleep(1000000)` instead of `sleep(1)`

Comment: Using PHP 7.0.0 RC1 with current pthreads-master I cannot reproduce this issue. It's behaving exactly as you say it should.

Comment: Very strange, I am running PHP 5.6.12 and pthreads version 2.0.10

Comment: Even with PHP-CLI 5.6.12 and pthreads 2.0.10 from [pecl.php.net](https://pecl.php.net/package/pthreads) I'm not experiencing this issue. Are you using some kind of special SAPI with output buffering?

Comment: I'm not really sure. My setup is just the basic Apache 2 that comes with OS X and I've upgraded to PHP 5.6 with homebrew and enabled thread safety.  I installed pthreads with pecl. In my phpinfo() it says that output buffering is set to 4096. Does that mean it is enabled, or just that it could be enabled with those settings?

Comment: Well, it should be a classic output buffering problem then. The author of pthreads [does not recommend](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/issues/447#issuecomment-115532325) writing anything to the output buffer from a thread (not even in plain PHP-CLI). This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31186883/2032498

Comment: Alright I got it sorta solved using by turning off output buffering in php.ini. It now outputs `1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5` like it should, however it still waits the 1 second before displaying all the output at once. I looked at the solution you posted and I don't think it is capable of sleeping between outputs, although please correct me if I'm wrong. Is there a way to display the first set of numbers without waiting for the second set to calculate?

Comment: No, I'm afraid that's not possible with the SAPI you're using. There must be a certain number of bytes in the tube before Apache starts pumping them to the client.

Comment: That's ok, I basically got what I wanted anyways. Thanks for your help, I never would've figured this out on my own (believe me, I tried for hours!)

Answer (score 0):

This is a copy-paste from PHP API Reference:

> After the run method is executed the Thread will exit immediately, it
>   will be joined with the creating Thread at the appropriate time.

I assume, the engine belives the appropriate time to join those threads is upon next loop iteration.

Comment: That is not the case. The thread will be joined upon object deletion or when [`Thread::join`](http://php.net/manual/thread.join()) is called.